# Siddhi Error connecting to JMS provider

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I tried to send events from WSO2 SP to activeMQ via [siddhi-io-jms extension](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-jms/api/latest/), but i have following error. **Error connecting to JMS provider. NamingException while obtaining initial context.**
I have followed 
this doc for support jms transporting https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Supporting+Different+Transports, put all necessary jar files to lib, also I set correctly @sink in siddhi app, *factory.initial* and *provider.url* are correct. Any idea, why SP can't connect to jms?

Answer (score 1):

According to OSGi JNDI spec, all the InitialContextFactories should be exposed as OSGi services. But activemq-client-5.x.x.jar file doesn't contain SPI, but rather they set system properties. This causes the NamingException while obtaining initial context. So we need to register those ICF to OSGi env.

For this we need to use the icf-provider.(sh|bat) tool within SP_HOME/bin. 
This will add a BundleActivator to the user provided jar/bundle which will register the user mentioned ICF implementation according to the OSGi JNDI spec.

e.g.

```
./icf-provider.sh org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory <Jar Directory/activemq-client-5.9.0.jar> <Destination>
```

Refer https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-io-jms/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use icf-provider tool, but it did nothing. No messages on terminal, no bundle in destination folder. I used command for windows.

Comment: Seems there is an open issue for icf-provider on windows environment  [#1599](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/issues/1599)

Comment: I tried to edit bat file of icf-provider, so I removed _-Dcarbon.home="%CARBON_HOME"_ property from java -cp command and now it's running, however there are errors in CustomBundleActivator.java like **package org.osgi.framework does not exist** or **method does not override or implement a method from a supertype**.

Comment: Now I get back carbon.home property to bat file, but change **-Dcarbon.home="%CARBON_HOME"** to _-Dcarbon.home=%CARBON_HOME%_ (removed quotes, added percent char). Now there is folowing error: ** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 11**

Comment: Finally I solved this. The bat file and java code were bad, so I change them and test. Now it's working. Here -> https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/issues/1599 I reproduced my solution.